# PHP: Any failure? How to make `echo $report` return right value trough `class validate`?

Tags: php, class, function, return-value

Why `echo $report` has empty value? Any failure in `class validate`?

How to make it return right value trough `class validate`?

```
<?php
class validate{
    function status($status){
        header('Location:',true,$status);
        $report="Error: $status";
    }
    function fine(){
        $report='Ok!';
    }
}
$validate=new validate($id);
//$id=0;
$id=(isset($id) ? $id : NULL);
(($id==0) ? $validate->fine() : $validate->status('404'));
echo $report; // Why it has empty value? How to solve it?
?>
```

Comment: Your validate class doesn't have a constructor, you don't need to pass $id when creating $validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it as a public variable in the class, set it using $this->report, and echo it using $validate->report.

Example:

```
class validate{
    public $report;
    function status($status){
        header('Location:',true,$status);
        $this->report="Error: $status";
    }
    function fine(){
        $this->report='Ok!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$report is a class variable in your validate object. `echo $report` is looking for a variable in the local scope, not your object. Try `echo $validate->report` instead.